# How to create a pretty URL?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-url-manager, pretty-urls

How can I create a pretty url like this
customer/index/amount/12000/location/in . In Yii1.1 it was available by default. it was easy to enable pretty url. In Yii2 if need pretty url I've to write rules for every action !!!

In Codeigniter you will get index.php/controller/action/parameter1/parameter2/parameter3
ie it does not expose action parameter variables, that too without writing any url rules!

===Edit===

pretty URL doesnt work for parameters if no rule is defined

below is my main.php

```
 'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [  '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                       '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                       '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',               
                    ],
        ],
```

i am getting a lot of 404's, like

192.168.1.3/~user/urshow/frontend/web/movies/movies_all
it would have work fine if it would be like this
192.168.1.3/~user/urshow/frontend/web/index.php?r=/movies/movies_all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to *config.php* and add

```
'components' => [
     ...
        'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
         ],
    ...
],
```